# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /pg2.php on line 318

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy escribiendo una sentencia INSERT y tengo un error que no logro resolver en la siguiente instrucción:

```
$stmt->bind_param("$tipo_var", $insert_valores);
```

Sucede que la variable $tipo_var va entrecomillada, para lograr que queden entrecomillados los tipos de cada elemento del "statement" que envío a MySQL.

Los datos reales que recibe el sistema son:

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiisssssssdiiiddsssidddssssssss', 
2016, 2, 1, 'texto1', 'texto2', 'texto3', 'texto4', 'texto5', 'texto6',
'texto7', 0.01, 1, 1, 1, 0.01, 0.01, 'texto8', 'texto9', 'texto10', 11,
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 'texto11', 'texto12', 'texto13', 'texto14', 'texto15',
'texto16', 'texto17', 'texto18')
```

Es decir, no encuentro que exista un error real entre la cadena de tipos y los parámetros enviados, siendo que se respeta el orden de cada tipo vs la variable enviada.

La conexión a la BD y los tipos correspondientes a cada dato que se envía a la BD son correctos, pero sigue dándome este error:

> **Warning:** mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in 
>   **/pg2.php** on line **318**

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: coloca tu sentencia insert tambien, ahi puede estar el error

Comment: Dudo ue sea la cláusula INSERT (que es así):
INSERT INTO proyectos(cpo1, cpo2, cpo3, cpo4, cpo5, cpo6, cpo7, cpo8, cpo9, cpo10, cpo11, cpo12, cpo13, cpo14, cpo15, cpo16, cpo17, cpo18, cpo19, cpo20, cpo21, cpo22, cpo23, cpo24, cpo25, cpo26, cpo27, cpo28, cpo29, cpo30, cpo31) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

El error es: "El número de elementos en la cadena de definición de tipo no coincide con el número de variables de enlace" Pero en todos los casos son 31 definiciones y 31 variables.

Comment: Has echo un echo de $tipo_var para comprobar que no hay espacios en blancos, u otros caracteres en el string?

Comment: Sí, **Juan Pinzón**, he probado haciendo _**echo**_ en todas partes del código, finalmente encontré el problema que comento aparte. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente, amigos, encontré cuál era el inconveniente y lo describo para aquellos que estén pasando por este mismo problema.
Casi tres días peleando con el código para encontrar esa respuesta:

La sentencia que yo escribía era:

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiisssssssdiiiddsssidddssssssss', 
2016, 2, 1, 'texto1', 'texto2', 'texto3', 'texto4', 'texto5', 'texto6',
'texto7', 0.01, 1, 1, 1, 0.01, 0.01, 'texto8', 'texto9', 'texto10', 11,
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 'texto11', 'texto12', 'texto13', 'texto14', 'texto15',
'texto16', 'texto17', 'texto18');
```

Y realmente estaría correcto, si "**bind_param()**" permitiera pasar valores en forma directa.
Lo cierto es que es necesario enviar una variable por cada valor que se envía, no es posible enviar los valores "desnudos" sino encapsulados dentro de una variable.

Es decir, el modo correcto de enviar la sentencia era:

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiisssssssdiiiddsssidddssssssss', $int1, $int2,
$int3, $string1, $string2, $string3, $string4, $string5, $string6,
$string7, $double1, $int4, $int5, $int6, $double2, $double3, $string8,
$string9, $string10, $int7, $double4, $double5, $double6, $string11,
$string12, $string13, $string14, $string15, $string16, $string17,
$string18);
```

De ese modo, se cargó la información en la BD sin ningún otro error en el código.

Evidentemente era una cuestión de sintaxis caprichosa de esta función, pero que seguramente debe guardar alguna lógica.

Gracias a quienes me han dado algunas pistas y que sirva a quienes lo puedan necesitar.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 31 signos de interrogación, pero 32 valores en tus parámetros.

Comment: Comienza con el cpo1 y llega al cpo 31 por lo tanto, son 31 parámetros y 31 signos de interrogación. No haz mirado bien.

Answer (score 0):

> Te dejo un ejemplo como puedes crear un informe de errores para trabajar con declaraciones **prepare()**

Con este pequeño informe podrás saber dónde persiste el fallo o en tu `sentencia SQL`, `ligando parametros marcadores` o `ejecutando sentncia`.

```
//Sentencia prepare.
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO tutabla (id,nombre,ip) VALUES (?,?,?)");

// dado que todas las operaciones siguientes necesitan un objeto de sentencia válido.
if ( false===$stmt ) {      
    exit('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$rc= $stmt->bind_param("iss",$id,$nombre,$ip_adres);

//nuevamente execute () es inútil si no puedes enlazar los parámetros.      
if ( false===$rc ) {        
    exit('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$rc=$stmt->execute();

// execute () puede fallar por varias razones. Y puede ser tan estúpido como alguien trompiezo con el cable de red.
if ( false===$rc ) {
    exit('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$stmt->close();
```

> Respecto al fallo, te lo esta diciendo en ingles: Número de elementos en la cadena de definición de tipo no coincide con el número de variables.

Comment: Muchas gracias **D.Bulten** por este código para validar errores, realmente me fue útil para el código, si bien no resolvió el problema.

Comment: De nada, te ahorra trabajo de busqueda muchas veces. Puedes subir el codigo original, desde la sentencia SQL, asi a simple vista no se ve ningun error. As probado tambien pasar el tipo directo (iiisds...) a bind_param, sin la variable $tipo_var?

Comment: No fue necesario reemplazar esa variable pues, funcionó perfectamente, el problema lo tenía al intentar enviar los datos que quería cargar en la BD sin estar dentro de una variable. 
El tema es que se requiere declarar **una** variable por cada **?** pero funciona perfectamente en este momento. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegro. De nada.